# How can I keep bugs out of the MacBook Pro's hinge vent?

Tags: macbook-pro

I've noticed that some flying bugs have an irritating habit of crawling into the hinge vent on my MacBook Pro (15-inch, Mid 2009).

I don't know what possesses them to go in there, maybe it looks like an inviting hidey-hole, but they obviously end up dying from the heat. I'm paranoid they'll eventually clog something. Bless the designer for the nice design, but it's next to impossible to fish dead bugs out of there! Ironically, because of the silent design there's also no huge gust of hot air to persuade them not to try climbing in there.

The problem is made worse when there's a light above the table drawing them in, but even without it the screen is a bright enough draw. I've seen them crash into the screen (or fall from an above light), and then make a mad dash straight into the vent. It's infuriating!

Has anyone else experienced this problem with bugs and that hinge vent? How did you [de-bug](http://instantrimshot.com/index.php?sound=rimshot&play=true) yours? My only workaround so far has been to surround myself with tons of other lights on to keep them as scattered as possible...

**Edit:** Looking back at this question I'm disappointed that I forgot to include any regional info. At the time I was in a house in the country in Queensland, Australia. Bugs inside the house are the norm rather than the exception. I may have to wait until Summer again (in December) before I can actually test to see if this was a seasonal thing for the bugs, as I haven't been bothered by them again since then.

Comment: I love this one ! :-P

Comment: This question is WIN, especially the tags…

Comment: indeed... EPIC WIN

Comment: [Grace Hooper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grace_Hopper) had the [same problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:H96566k.jpg) back in 1947.

Comment: Well, guess who is not buying that model... I could not live with that, my macbook is always near my head... You found a solution?  Or did you go mad?

Comment: Well so far I haven't had any more bug problems, but that might just be due to staying away from those kinds of bugs. It's probably a seasonal thing, so I'd have to wait until next year to test it again. I wouldn't let this fringe case dissuade you from buying a MBP

Comment: +1 because you wrote "hidey-hole" in your question. And now you've got me wondering what's gone and crawled up in to my MBPro's vent and died...

Comment: +1 because I live in the exact opposite place, in Vancouver Canada. I have not even seen a bug in months, and that's how I like it.

Comment: +1 Because I just saw some little gnat of some sort crawl into my new 2011 MBP last night.  Luckily I was able to turn it up side down and it fell out.  It did make me start thinking though...

Comment: @Adam Lewis So I wasn't imagining it! :)

Comment: This is my understanding of Australia, which this question confirms: http://i.imgur.com/mTXhsOr.jpg

Answer (score 3):

Hmmm....I have a pc and it's bug free.

---

[non-troll answer]

Ok, ok....you might try flushing the vent openings with canned air while the computer is off.  Turn the can upside down so that you can actually get that super cold dangerous liquid in there.  Maybe there's some kind of scent that's drawing them in (is it the same species?).

Comment: The same scent? Like bug-musk!?